# How to change pingTimeout socket.io nodejs

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, vue-component, client-side

Quite new to sockets.

Figured out that my nodejs client socket has a pingTimoeut default set to 5000ms. I want to change the default pingTimeout... Have googled and looked here but haven't found the way to do it in my case.

Below is part of the code I'm working on:

```
const io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);
```

Then the following code inside a vue component.

```
this.socket = io.connect()
```

How do I change the pingTimeout on this particular socket instance?

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {'pingInterval': 2000, 'pingTimeout': 5000});
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know where to put it. Works like a charm!

Comment: what about the frontend javascript?
Should I change to this code too, or does it not matter?
const socket = io(http, {'pingInterval': 2000, 'pingTimeout': 5000});